# if constexpr block not compiling

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, if-constexpr

I have a class that can inherit from an empty struct or from a struct with some members, depending on a `bool`. Using that same `bool`, I am adding an `if constexpr` block to access the members of the base class, but I am getting a compiler error

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

template <typename J0, typename J1>
struct HasFriction {
    constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template <> struct HasFriction<A,B> {
    constexpr static bool value = true;
};

template <bool> struct Friction { };
template <> struct Friction<true> { int value = 4; };

template <typename J0, typename J1>
struct MyStruct : public Friction<HasFriction<J0, J1>::value> {};

int main()
{
    if constexpr (HasFriction<A, C>::value) {
        MyStruct<A,C> f;
        return f.value;
    } else {
        MyStruct<A,C> no_f;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Why is this not working, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

> Why is this not working and how should I fix it?

In order to work `if constexpr` (i.e. discard the false statement at compile time),  you need to make it template depended.

From *[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If)*, under the `if constexpr` section:

> **Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked.** `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the `#if` preprocessing directive:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     if constexpr(false) {
>         int i = 0;
>         int *p = i; // Error even though in discarded statement
>     }
> }
> ```

Therefore, the fix is to wrap the statement into a template function, as follows:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> auto func()
{
    if constexpr (HasFriction<T1, T2>::value) {
        MyStruct<A, C> f;
        return f.value;
    }
    else {
        MyStruct<A, C> no_f;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now in `main()`

```
func<A, B>();
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GsjMcrz53)